# What is the syntax for adding multiple strings to one variable in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list

Okay the thing i want to do is make a variable like Line = "hey","you",Mom".

Then later I want to be able to call Line 0 and get the string "hey".

I have something like this:

```
String[] history = new String "hey","you","Mom";

public String getLine(int index)
{
   if (index < 0 || index >= this.history.length)
       return null;
}
```

But this is not working..

How do i make this list?  I'm new with the syntax in java.

Comment: You may need to look for a starters guide or something like that :)

Comment: Indeed. And that's not an insult, we're all new at things periodically (learning new things is good!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```
String[] history = new String[] { "hey", "you", "Mom" };
```

Comment: Thanks just what i needed :) hard when i'm not used to the syntax.

Comment: Don't forget to select accepted answer if it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] history = new String[] {"hey","you","Mom"};
String hey = history[0];
```

This creates a String array with size 3 initialized with the strings `hey`, `you` and `Mom`.

Another option is to use a `List`:

```
List<String> history = Arrays.asList("hey","you","Mom");
String hey = history.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't return anything when the index was in range:
And array initialization works like this:

```
String[] history = new String[] { "hey","you","Mom" };

public String getLine(int index)
{
  if (index < 0 || index >= this.history.length)
    return null;
  else
    return history[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] history = new String[] {"hey", "you", "Mom"};
```

Alternatives:

- `List<String> words = Arrays.asList("hey", "you", "Mom");`
- `String str = "Hey you Mom"; String[] words = str.split(" ")`